# How does yield know the return type

Tags: scala

I have following code snippet:

```
sealed trait Either[+E, +A] {

  def map2[EE >: E, B, C](b: Either[EE, B])(f: (A, B) => C): Either[EE, C] =

    for {
      aa <- this
      bb <- b
    } yield (f(aa, bb))

}

case class Left[+E](get: E) extends Either[E, Nothing]

case class Right[+A](get: A) extends Either[Nothing, A]
```

How the for comprehension knows, which type to return? For me it is not clear, that type C is return `Either[EE, C]`.

Comment: Does this code compiles?

Comment: yes. I tried `val t = Right(3).map2(Right(5))((a,b) => a * b)` and got `Right(15)`.

Comment: Error:(56, 13) value flatMap is not a member of  `Either[E,A]
      aa <- this`. For me it does not like `this` in `aa <- this`

Comment: I do not get any compiler error.

Comment: The example is from https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/errorhandling/Either.scala.

Comment: @zero_coding That example includes map and flatmap definitions which you left out of your question.  You need map and flatmap (and filter for some features) to use for comprehension

Comment: OK, I've got it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For comprehensions get desugared by the compiler into calls to `flatMap`, `map` and `withFilter`.

```
for {
  aa <- this
  bb <- b
} yield (f(aa, bb))
```

==

```
this.flatMap(aa => b.map(bb => f(aa, bb)))
```

So the result of the for comprehension depends on the type signature and implementation of the `flatMap` and `map` methods.

Comment: which `flatMap` is going to call, from standard library?

Comment: The `flatMap` that's defined on the class of which `this` is an instance.

Comment: How would `for comprehensions` for map look like? `for { aa <- this } yield f(aa)`?

Comment: Yes, `for { aa <- this } yield f(aa)` would be translated to a single `map`.